# method cannot be resolved

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to add a timerbar to my interface but when I try to setValue in my progress bar setValue method cannot be resolved. What I am I doing wrong here can anyone please tell me how to sort this problem. Thanks for your time.

```
package com.leopard.spring;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.StyleSheet;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;

//import com.vaadin.flow.component.table.Table;
//import com.vaadin.ui.Table;


@Route("Playboard")
@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/style.css")
public class Playboard extends VerticalLayout {
    // private Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);

    //    /
    public Playboard() {
        setLayout();
        addClassName("play-board");
        setSizeFull();

    }

HorizontalLayout timer = new HorizontalLayout();
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(0.600);
        add(timer);}}
```

Comment: ProgressBar has no setValue method. So ... don't call it.

Comment: I guess you want to use Vaadin's `ProgressBar`, not the JavaFX one. Change your imports, if that's the case.

Comment: @JuliaSamól Thanks a lot it worked